# Dynamic Height of Image

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm a CSS amateur and designing a website. I have played about with this for days so I am here.

On the left hand side I have a vertical menu. Floated to the left of this I have a picture which is about 75% width. Below this I have two divs(orange and green boxes with yellow line).

It is a dynamic layout and basically when I resize my browser I want the height of the image to be the same height as the vertical menu i.e. no blue space. It is fine when I don't resize my browser but after a blue gap appears between the image and the divs below. I think it may be something to do with the browser preserving the aspect ratio of the picture but I want the image to fill this space.

I have played about for hours with different %'s etc but no success so far.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated?

[image: Float Div]

Code:
Yellow Contact US menu option(all menu options are the same)

```
#link_side6{
float:left;
width:100%;
clear:left;
padding-left:0%;
padding-top:6%;
padding-bottom:6%;
padding-right:0%;
background-color:#f8e32b;
}
```

Image divs:

Container div for image

```
 #banner{
float:left;
width:75%;
margin-right:0%;
margin-left:0%;
margin-bottom:0%;
margin-top:0%;
 }
```

Actual Image

```
 #changer{
float:left;
margin-top:0%;
width:100%; 
}
```

Orange Div:

```
#welcome{
clear:left;
text-align:left;
padding:3%;
float:left;
width:60%;
background-color:#faa733;
padding-bottom:12.5%;

 }
```

Green div

```
#upcoming{
float:left;
padding:0.3%;
width:33%;
margin-top:0%;
min-width:185px;
background-color:#63d456;
border-left:thick solid #f8e327;
}
```

The image changes and acts as links to other pages.

Comment: Can you post `div`s and their style? can't really help you just by looking at a picture.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ ;)

Comment: Cant be a background image as it is a "slideshow" i.e. changing image

Comment: so you will need to look for a responsive slideshow plugin

Comment: Cant find a plugin online which the images can act as links

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that the three buttons on the left have a fixed width and height, you could set the image as background-image to a UL which wraps the buttons and have a 100% width. The resize the image using background-size:cover;

```
ul#header {width:100%; background-image:url(pathtoyourimage); background-size:cover; background-repeat:no-repeat;}

<ul id="header">
   <li><a href="...">Join Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="...">News</a></li>
   <li><a href="...">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Depending on what importance have the image itself, you could play around with background-position.

Comment: Cant be a background image as it is a "slideshow" i.e. changing image